# Matlab: How can I create buffer from coastline 400KM?

Tags: matlab

I have two ideas, but both met with difficulties.

1. I calculated all points 400km from the coastline, but it's disordered. I don't know how to connect them along the coastline.()

[image: Fig.1]

2. I used the function bufferm(lat, lon, bufferwidth) to calculate the buffer area, but I don't know how to determine the bufferwidth.

[image: Fig.2]

There are any methods to solve the questions mentioned above?
Or is there any other way to draw the buffer area 400km from the coastline?